# php how to pass a variable through a button

Tags: php, css, html

i'm doing a little e-commerce for school and I don't know how to pass the name of the selected product to another page when the user click on the 'see more info' of the same product (like amazon basically). So, I know how session work, but I don't know how to add to a specified variable of the session a value when I click a button.

Comment: When you select any product it will take value of that product in $_POST variable if you set value in specific tag.

Comment: the easiest way would be to generate an url for the button like `www.mydomain.com/product.php?id=123`. Another way would be to add the product id to the session $_SESSION['current-product'] =123, direct to the next page and in the code of that page check for current-product in the session. Don't forget to start the session.

Comment: Accept the answer that works for you to close the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to pass a session variable to your form action, use `<input type="hidden" name="any_name" value="value">` and simply use `$_POST["any_name"]` in your action script.

To pass it via URL, use `http://www.yourwebsite.com/step2.php?any_name=value` where it will be visible in the URL. To pass more than 1 value, `http://www.yourwebsite.com/step2.php?any_name=value&second_name=value2`.

Answer (score 0):

use get methode 
ex : exemple.com/index.php?prod=12 ;

$prod = $_GET['prod'] ;

Comment: but where i put the form with method post? It works with a single button?

Comment: you can use js button event ....

html : `<button onclick="rederect(id)">click me</button>`

`<script>
function rederect(id){
 window.location = "exemple.com/index.php?prod="+id ;
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

<a href="more_info.php?prod_id=$id">Product</a>

**Then at more_info.php :**

// Collect the product id
if(isset($_GET['prod_id'])){

$the_product_id = $_GET['prod_id'];

// Get the details now from the database

}

Comment: ty very much :)